# Re-running SonarQube failed. "Unable to create root temp directory"

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, windows-10, sonarqube-scan

I successfully run the demo project with SonarQube + SonarLint for Eclipse. Then I add to this project java classes to analyze and try to re-run but Solar keeps to throw the error - "Unable to create root temp directory. "
The LocalHost is up. Once again, the first demo run was successful. For more information, please, take a look on print-screen.

The successful demo run : 
https://gyazo.com/770ac87cd20cd2729c96ec5518244d47

Error from Eclipse ( I also install sonarLint plug-in ) : 
https://gyazo.com/3002ef55d3e306fc7a73683156c69d66

Error from CMD ( I'm using Windows 10 ) : 
https://gyazo.com/e56480776778d649d4ad029392d1e35d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that SonarQube Scanner was unable to create the necessary temp files to run the analysis. You should check file existence and permissions.

Comment: On the first glance, everything fine. 1) There is some .sonar folder 2) security properties tell me that some unknown entity ( have access to change folder ) Please, take a look :  https://gyazo.com/d2c3619bd46c6bd570f3581ccf91628e

Comment: I mean, sorry, but still isn't working. Thx for your attention but the problem is not solved. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is kind of dirty solution but when I delete the folder ".sonar" in my project the problem was solved.

https://gyazo.com/4855669256d0cc2a95b50dc5779fb814